# Is there a difference between a wifi usb adapter's chip and a router's wifi chip?

Tags: wireless-networking

Is there a difference between the wifi chip in a usb adapter and a router's wifi chip?

Is there going to be a performance difference if I use a laptop or raspberry pi as an access point compared to a router? *(- Let say that the router works only on 2.4Ghz and is capable of 802.11n and the same goes for the usb adapter.)*

Comment: No, I don't think so. I use my RasPi as a wifi router, too, with two usb wifi adapters. One of them is running as AP without any problems so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the device has sufficient CPU power to deal with the traffic, WPA encryption and what not there is really no difference.
Many commercial router/access-points have a motherboard that is very similar to the hardware of a RaspPI. A laptop, even an old one, will be much faster.
I have build multiple routers/AP's with 8 year old PC's (1.6 GHz P4, 512 MB RAM) using the pfSense Linux-based router. I routinely use these to handle multiple (v)LAN's, NAT, firewall, proxy-server and run as AP (multiple SSID's) all at the time. CPU load is rarely above 20%.

USB will introduce a small bottleneck compared to a hardwired chip because of the USB protocol overhead, but as long there is no other USB equipment connected to the same USB root hub that shouldn't be noticable, unless you are really saturating the WIFI dongle continuously. The USB connection will max out effectively at about 400 mbits/s. That should just be enough for 2.4G, 802.11n as long as you don't try to operate a dozen clients at max speed.